# If $\cos\pi x=x^2-x-5/4$ then the value of $x$ is

Tags: trigonometry

If $\cos\pi x=x^2-x-5/4 \,$ then the value of $x$ is?

I have completed: $\cos \pi x=(4x^2-4x-5)/4$

$\cos \pi x=3/8 \,$ or $1/8$

Comment: You even cannot solve $x=\cos(x)$ analytically. Only numerical methods could be used. By the way, did you plot the function ?

Comment: i dont know how to do @ClaudeLeibovici thats why i asked here

Comment: Try out gnuplot with commands 'plot cos(pi * x), x * x - x - 5.0/4' and then probably 'plot [-1:3] cos(pi * x), x * x - x - 5.0/4'

Comment: We have $$-1\le\frac{4x^2-4x-5}4\le1$$  $$\iff-4\le(2x-1)^2-6\le4\iff2\le(2x-1)^2\le10$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee next what to do.you can post it as answer so u can get votes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

As I said in a comment, this kind of equations cannot be solved analytically and only numerical method should be used.

The function you look the zero's of is $$f(x)=\cos(\pi x)-(x^2-x-\frac{5}{4})$$ Since $-1 \le \cos(y) \le 1$, you see (I let you doing it) that the range of $x$ which contains the solutions is quite limited (see  lab bhattacharjee's comment).

If you plot the function, you will notice that there is a root close to $-0.5$ and another close to $2.0$.

Now, since we have a reasonable starting value $x_0$, let us apply Newton method which shall update the guess according to $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: sorry i dont know this method i am new to this method

Comment: Then, plot the function and zoom the areas I mentioned. There is no analytical solution. Cheers :-)